# Download data from Portal using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to download a hosted layer from our portal and save to a file geodatabase.

Following [Using ArcPy to copy a portal feature service to a fgdb feature class](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/using-arcpy-to-copy-a-portal-feature-service-to-a/td-p/4281):

I've tried:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

url_gis = r'https://maps.something.se/arcgis/home/'
url_fl = r'https://maps.something.se/server/rest/services/Hosted/service_asfdasfadsfasafdsafdsafdsafsafas653757237adfagdagd.'

user = "username"
pwd = "password"

#fgdb = # path to file geodatabase
#fc = # name of feature class

gis = GIS(url_gis, user, pwd)
fl = FeatureLayer(url_fl)
fs = fl.query() #No errors until this line
```

> builtins.Exception: A general error occurred: maximum recursion depth
> exceeded while calling a Python object

Am I on the right track with this or are there some easier way to download the data using ArcPy?

Comment: This isn't ArcPy, it's the ArcGIS API for Python. If there isn't a FeatureClassToFeatureClass equivalent, you need to go the old-fashioned route of a nested row writer within a row query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ArcPy

```
import arcpy

## url to the feature layer
fl = "https://services-eu1.arcgis.com/*******/arcgis/rest/services/County_Boundaries/FeatureServer/0"

## file geodatabase path
## NOTE you can use arcpy to create a geodatabase rather than having an existing
gdb = r"C:\Path\to\Documents\fgdb.gdb"

## path for saving output feature class
out_fc = "{0}\\exported_layer".format(gdb)

## create feature class from feature layer
## you can also use FeatureClassToFeatureClass in older versions of ArcGIS Pro
arcpy.conversion.ExportFeatures(fl, out_fc)
```

Using ArcGIS API for Python to download entire feature service.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

## required inputs
export_title = "fs_export"
export_format = "File Geodatabase"
save_path = r"C:\path\to\folder"

## access agol
agol = GIS("home")

## access the feature service
item = agol.content.get("FS_ITEM_ID")

export = item.export(
    title = export_title,
    export_format = export_format
)

export.download(
    save_path = save_path
)
```

Using ArcGIS API for Python to extract an individual layer.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

## required inputs
out_fc = "fs_export"
gdb = r"C:\Path\to\agol.gdb"

## access agol
agol = GIS("home")

## access the feature service
item = agol.content.get("FS_ITEM_ID")

## access feature layer of choice
fl = item.layers[0]

## use query to return a feature set object
export = fl.query()

## save the feature set as a feature class in a gdb
export.save(gdb, out_fc)
```